# Minifilter which tag should be used with file system string buffer?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, unicode-string, minifilter

I am developing a minifilter to redirect open file from kernel-mode.

I redirect file name by changing `Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName`. But I don't know tag which should be used to release and allocate this unicode string buffer.

I used:

```
pFileName = &Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName;
if (pFileName->Buffer != NULL)
    ExFreePool(pFileName->Buffer);
pFileName->Length = gRedirectFullFilePath.Length;
pFileName->MaximumLength = pFileName->Length;
pFileName->Buffer = (PWCH) ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, pFileName->MaximumLength); // This is line 392
```

But when I used `Code Analysis` to build project, I got a warning as below:

```
C28159  Consider using another function instead Consider using 'ExAllocatePoolWithTag'
instead of 'ExAllocatePool'. Reason: No tag interferes with debugging.
FsMiniFilter    fsminifilter.c  392
```

And

```
C28751  Banned usage of ExAllocatePool and its variants
Banned usage of ExAllocatePool and its variants:
ExAllocatePool is a banned API for improved error handling purposes.
FsMiniFilter    fsminifilter.c  392
```

So I must change to `ExAllocatePoolWithTag`

```
pFileName->Buffer = (PWCH) ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, pFileName->MaximumLength,
                                WHAT_IS_TAG_HERE);
```

What should I use for `WHAT_IS_TAG_HERE`?

(I am using 32-bit Windows 7, MS Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, and WDK 8.0.)

Comment: samjeba's answer is correct, but I would also add that you should maybe look at the [SimRep Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SimRep-File-System-9a4e2206/view/SourceCode). It shows what you're doing here, but also will reuse the existing buffer if there is enough space, and covers the Windows 7 and later function IoReplaceFileObjectName to accomplish this. Allocating your own buffer can result in you failing driver verifier checks because your driver allocates but Io Manager frees.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Description here

[ExAllocatePoolWithTag routine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544520(v=vs.85).aspx)

TAG are unique signature to identify the Memory allocation to a driver component. So Create TAG for your driver which would help debuggers or verifier to identify your driver.